# Is it possible to bulk update in primefaces In-Cell Editing datatable?

Tags: jsf, datatable, primefaces

I'm using primefaces In-Cell Editing   datatable in my application.i need to update few records by ticking respective checkboxes, is there any way to do with primefaces?
Thanks in advance

Comment: How about doing the updates on the underlying data objects and refresh the datatable

Comment: still i need to have the incell editing for individual record. will it cause any problem if i use checkboxes?